# ReactJS code with and without class definitions: which one is preferred?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Structurally, how different are these two code? Aren't they (almost) equivalent? In what situations one is preferred over the other?

```
var Hello = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        return ( <div>Hello World</div> );
    }
});
React.render(<Hello />, document.body);
```

and

```
class SampleApplication extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return ( <div>Hello  World</div> );
  }
}

React.render(<SampleApplication />, document.body);
```

Comment: I guess you would use ES6 classes if you are using ES6 and `React.createClass` if not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well the first one is ES5 and the second one is ES6.

Code-wise they're doing the same thing tho.

You can read about ES6 classes support in the [React.js Blog](https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2015/01/27/react-v0.13.0-beta-1.html).

---

The biggest difference is that you'll have next to *zero* native support for the ES6 code in the browsers of today.

More than likely, you will want to add a build step to your application that transpiles the ES6 syntax to an ES5-compatible syntax.

A very popular and very suitable transpiler is [babel.js](http://babeljs.io).

---

Personally, I'm using ES6 for everything now and transpiling to ES5 where necessary.

Comment: There's also zero JSX support in browsers :-p